# Cant resolve my external domain name internally

Tags: reverse-proxy, windows-server-2016, pfsense

i have an active directory domain called example.com which uses an reverse proxy.
when im outside of the internal network test.example.com and example.com/test works, but inside my network they dont resolve.
dns is set to my DC controller, but when i change to 8.8.8.8 it works, if i choose my router it wont work because dns is set to my DC controller in the dhcp settings.
is there anything i can do ?

im using: Pfsense, lets encrypt and Windows Server 2016

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As your local domain and your remote domain are the same you need to setup a split DNS setup.

That mean you need to recreate the external entry in your local DNS.

In your DC create all external entry, like test.example.com or www.example.com and direct it to the correct external IP.

The only difficult IP to change is the domain name, as if in a browser a user type the short name, aka example.com, it will resolve to your DC and you can’t change that one, but if you can run a IIS on the DC you can use a IIS rewrite module that would rewrite example.com to www.example.com, thus would redirect to the correct IP.

Some admins create the local domain under a subdomain to prevent such headache. In your case it would had been like corpo.example.com for your local domain, and example.com would be hold on the external for query that target it.